# Dividir hora en 3 variables - PHP - explode

Tags: php

Estoy intentando dividir una variable de fecha y hora en 3 variables para poder hacer después la inserción a la base de datos ya que dichos campos están separados, para ello estoy utilizando un código similar a este:

```html
<?php

$fecha = '2019-01-09';
list($anio, $mes, $dia) = explode("-", $fecha); 
echo "Fecha: $fecha <br>";
echo "Año: $anio <br />"; 
echo "Mes: $mes <br />"; 
echo "Dia: $dia <br />"; 

$tiempo = '4:36 PM';

list($hora, $minutos) = explode(':', $tiempo);

list($min, $meria) = explode (' ', $minutos);


echo "Hora: $hora <br>";
echo "Minutos: $minutos <br>";
echo "Min: $min <br>";
echo "Meria: $meria";

?>
```

Con la variable $fecha no tuve ningún inconveniente ya que el carácter a excluir siempre era el mismo que es "-", pero con la hora tengo : y un espacio, logre resolver el problema haciendo un explode para cada carácter, pero me preguntaba si podía hacer eso solamente en un explode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para no dar tantas vueltas mareando los datos, lo más simple sería unir la fecha y la hora y crear a partir de ellos un objeto `DateTime`.  Luego, con la ayuda de `format` puedes obtener la parte de ese objeto que desees en la forma que la desees. En PHP, cuando trabajas con un verdadero objeto `DateTime` puedes obtener una gran cantidad de partes de ese objeto y en diferentes representaciones ([aquí puedes ver la lista](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php)).

Por ejemplo:

```
$fecha = '2019-01-09';
$tiempo = '4:36 PM';
/*Unimos fecha y tiempo*/
$strDateTime="$fecha $tiempo";

/*Creamos el objeto indicando qué formato tiene la cadena que une fecha y tiempo*/
$mDate=DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i A', $strDateTime);

/*Obtenemos cualquier parte del objeto que necesitemos*/
$dd=$mDate->format('d');
$mm=$mDate->format('m');
$yy=$mDate->format('Y');
$hh=$mDate->format('h');
$ii=$mDate->format('i');
$aa=$mDate->format('A');
echo "Día: $dd ; Mes: $mm ; Año: $yy ; Hora: $hh ; Minutos: $ii ; AM/PM: $aa";
```

**Salida:**

```
Día: 09 ; Mes: 01 ; Año: 2019 ; Hora: 04 ; Minutos: 36 ; AM/PM: PM
```

> Aunque realmente lo más conveniente si pudieras sería *normalizar* tu
>   modelo de datos, creando una sola columna del tipo `DATETIME` en la
>   base de datos donde guardarías por entero el valor: `2019-01-09 4:36 PM`.
>
> No tiene ningún sentido usar ¡6 columnas! para guardar un dato
>   que es el mismo. El control de errores se hace complicado y cuando hay
>   que hacer cálculos o presentar el dato completo hay que reunirlo de
>   nuevo, con el mismo trabajo con que se disgregó. Todo un trabajo
>   innecesario por el hecho de haber separado en el diseño de datos algo
>   que siempre debió permanecer junto.
>
> A veces se comete el error de diseñar el modelo de datos pensando en el formato de salida. Es un error guardar datos formateados, eso sería limitar la potencialidad de las bases de datos y de los lenguajes de programación. Es mucho mejor guardar los datos como lo que son y luego aplicar el formato a la salida, según la necesidad concreta para ese contexto donde necesitemos los datos. Así, puede que en algunos casos necesites representar la hora con  `AM` o `PM` y en otros que quieras representarla como `16:36`. Para eso existen métodos como `format`, tanto en PHP  como en MySQL y cualquier otro lenguaje de programación o manejador de base de datos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta padre, siempre sus respuestas son excelentes y muy completas, me has ayudado un montón.

Comment: @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz me alegro de que te haya servido. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

preg_split de php es lo que necesitas https://www.php.net/preg_split

divide un string usando una expresion regular, en este caso usé una muy básica para : y espacio en blanco.

```
$time = '4:36 PM';
$split = preg_split('/[:| ]/', $time);
print_r($split);

Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 36
    [2] => PM
)
```

**EDITO**

---

Como veo que eres algo principiante, con tu mismo ejemplo para asignar a variables, se hace así:

```
$time = '4:36 PM';
list($hora, $minuto, $meridiano) = preg_split('/[:| ]/', $time);

echo $hora.'<br>';
echo $minuto.'<br>';
echo $meridiano.'<br>';
```

Comment: pero no lo necesito en un array, sino cada uno en una variable distinta.

Comment: con el array que te devuelve simplemente lo asignas a una variable $hour = $split[0], $minute = $plit[1], $meridian = $split[2], abajo te pusieron el ejemplo para asignar los indices del array a variables.

Comment: actualicé el código para que lo uses igual que en tu ejemplo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, corrió bien, marqué tu respuesta como correcta.

Answer (score 2):

Intenta así:

```
$arr = preg_split('/[:| ]/', $tiempo);

$hora = $arr[0];
$minuto = $arr[1];
$ampm = $arr[2];
```